# copy a map into another map

Tags: c++

I have a map like this:

```
map<prmNode,vector<prmEdge>,prmNodeComparator> nodo2archi;
```

I need to have an identical copy of this map. How is the fast way to make this?
I have tried this:

```
map<prmNode,vector<prmEdge>,prmNodeComparator> copiamap( nodo2archi );
```

but it doesn't work. The copiamap is empty.
Thank you very much

Comment: Just use the copy constructor built into `std::map`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the map's copy constructor:

```
map<prmNode,vector<prmEdge> > nodo2archi;
map<prmNode,vector<prmEdge> > acopy( nodo2archi ) ;
```

This code, which copies a map, prints the same size (1) for each.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef  map <int, int> MapType;

int main() {
    MapType m1;
    m1.insert( make_pair( 1, 1 ) );
    cout << m1.size() << endl;
    MapType m2( m1 );
    cout << m2.size() << endl;
}
```

If your own code really doesn't copy, then I would suspect bugs in the copy constructors or the comparison functions for the contained types are screwing up memory somehow.

Comment: I have tried this:
map<prmNode,vector<prmEdge>,prmNodeComparator> copiamap( nodo2archi );
but it doesn't work. The copiamap is empty.

Comment: with an int works, but with my objects doesn't work. I don't have idea why

Comment: @livio8495 See my last para above.

Comment: @livio8495 Might be nice to add  a sentence or two to your answer, saying what the solution was. That way, if the problem is asked about again, we can usefully refer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if instead of:

`map<prmNode,vector<prmEdge>,prmNodeComparator> copiamap( nodo2archi );`

You use

`map<prmNode,vector<prmEdge>,prmNodeComparator> copiamap = nodo2archi;`

I agree with others you are missing something somewhere, but can you test?